# How do I pass callbacks in javascript function?

Tags: javascript, callback

I was watching [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ) talk on the event loop in JavaScript and it explained how "callbacks" are executed. And I wrote this to see how it works:

```
function show(str) {
  return 'Hello ' + str;
}

// This does not work
show('World', function (data) {
  console.log(data);
});

// This works
console.log(show('Sayantan'));
```

Maybe I got this whole thing wrong. But how do I pass callbacks as parameters like the way I tried to do. For example in jQuery's `$.get()` or `$.post()` where we give a callback to do what we want to do after the response came back. So I hoping the function call would print 'Hello World' in console as that's what I defined in my callback. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take the callback and call it in the function `show` with the wanted parameter.

```js
function show(str, cb) {
    return cb('Hello ' + str);
}

show('World', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You're almost there - the only thing you didn't do is handle the callback in `show`:

```
function show(str,callback) {
   callback('Hello ' + str); // this will execute the anonymous function with 'Hello ' + `str` as the variable
   return 'Hello ' + str;
 }
```

Comment: This is only printing "world".

Comment: I wasn't sure what you were trying to do, I've updated my answer - you can remove the return as well if you don't need it